# File reading and store as int in C

Tags: c

Here is the scenario. I have a matrix in a file which contains numbers and the letter x. x means that no path occurs. I am trying to read a file and storing it in an int array. But it doesn't work well. The value of x doesn't change to 99999.

```
graph.txt
0 x x x x x
x 0 x x x x
x x 0 x x x
x x x 0 x x
x x x x 0 x
x x x x x 0

this is the result. 

 0    2291852    1988293161    5507688    2291916    1988315945
 3    1988315897    1238539516    3    1988897120    0
 3    0    1988897120    2291908    1988273218    5508800
 2291920    1988293445    19    2291976    1988390633    1988897120
 1988390584    1238539576    2293452    0    2293256    2291936
 1988339419    2293700    1988398293    1064569584    160    0
```

here is the code

```
 # define x 99999
 int main(){

char filename[200]="";

char buffer[200];

int ch;

FILE * fileIn;

FILE * fileInn;

    printf("\tEnter Filename> ");

    scanf("%s", &filename); //Enter filename


        if((fileIn = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) { //error filename

            printf("File could not be opened. \n");}

        else {


            while(!feof(fileIn)){ //counts number of rows 

                    ch = fgetc(fileIn);

                    if(ch == '\n') size+=1;

            }



            rewind(fileIn);



            if(!(feof(fileIn))){ //puts the matrix in an array

                int input[size][size];

                for(a = 0; a<size; a++) {

                    for(b=0; b<size; b++) {

                        fscanf(fileIn, "%d", &input[a][b]);     

                    }

                }

                printMatrix(input);



            }else printf("EOF");
    }

}
```

What I want to happen is, when the matrix element is an x. x will be read as 99999 and store it in the input array. and if it is an integer it will just directly be stored in the input array.

Comment: That "#define x 99999" isn't going to do what you think -- it has no effect whatsoever at runtime while reading the input.  Also, if you declare `input[size][size]` inside that `if` statement, you can't rely on being able to access it outside the scope enclosed by the braces, as you do with the `printMatrix(input)` statement.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to read an array from a file. Your challenge adds a simple complication that you must **read both characters and integers** from the file and then add the elements to the array based on whether the characters represent digits or whether it is the single character 'x' which you then substitute the value '99999'.

The easiest way to do this is with **line-oriented input** reading a line-at-a-time from the data file and then parsing each line as needed. I recommend you make friends with `getline` for all your line-input needs. It provides a number of benefits over `fgets` or `scanf`, and takes no more effort than either of the others.

Once you have your line of data read from input, you need to split the line into words. `strtok` is the tool of choice, otherwise you can write a custom parser (depending on your needs). `strtok` works fine here. As you split the lines into words, you can test each of the words to determine if they represent a number or a character. There are many ways to do this. One simple/efficient way in your case is simply to test if the first character is an `'x'`. If so substitute `99999` for the array value, if not, just use `atoi (word)` to convert the word into an integer.

The following is one hack at doing all the above. Read through it and let me know if you have any questions.

**oops originally had '9999' instead of '99999' -- fixed**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input. Usage: %s input_file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;      /* forces getline to allocate space for buf */
    ssize_t read = 0;       /* number of characters read by getline     */
    size_t n = 0;           /* limit number of chars to 'n', 0 no limit */
    int idx = 0;            /* simple index counter for array           */
    int row = 0;            /* simple row counter index for array       */
    int *col = NULL;        /* simple column counter for array          */
    int *array = NULL;      /* array to hold integers read from file    */
    char *delim = " \n";    /* delimeter for strtok to parse line       */

    FILE *ifp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (!ifp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nerror: failed to open file: '%s'\n\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    array = calloc (MAX_SIZE, sizeof (array));      /* allocate MAX_SIZE elements           */
    col   = calloc (MAX_SIZE, sizeof (col));        /* allocate MAX_SIZE elements           */

    while ((read = getline (&line, &n, ifp)) != -1) /* read each line in file with getline  */
    {
        char *tmp = NULL;                           /* pointer to hold strtok results       */

        tmp = strtok (line, delim);                 /* first call to strtok using 'line'    */

        if (*tmp == 'x')                            /* test if tmp[0] = 'x'                 */
            array [idx++] = 99999;                  /* if so, assign value of '99999'       */
        else
            array [idx++] = atoi (tmp);             /* if not, assign result of atoi (tmp)  */

        col[row]++;                                 /* increase column count                */

        while ((tmp = strtok (NULL, delim)) != NULL) /* all remaining strtok calls use NULL */
        {
            if (*tmp == 'x')                        /* same tests as above                  */
                array [idx++] = 99999;
            else
                array [idx++] = atoi (tmp);

            col[row]++;                             /* increase column count                */

        }
        row++;                                      /* increase row count                   */
    }

    if (line) free (line);                          /* free memory allocated by getline     */

    int it = 0;                                     /* simple index iterator                */

    while (col[it])                                 /* simple loop to validate columns      */
    {
        if (it > 0)
            if (col[it-1] != col[it])
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "Error: inconsistent colums of data read\n");
                return 0;
            }
        it++;
    }

    printf ("\nProperties of array read from file '%s':\n\n", argv[1]);
    printf ("  elements: %d\n  rows    : %d\n  cols    : %d\n", idx, row, col[0]);

    printf ("\nArray elements:\n\n");

    for (it = 0; it < idx; it++)                    /* output information stored in array   */
    {
        if ((it+1) % col[0] == 0 && it > 0)
            printf (" %5d\n", array[it]);
        else
            printf (" %5d", array[it]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    if (array) free (array);                        /* free memory allocated to arrays      */
    if (col)   free (col);

    return 0;
}
```

**input file:**

```
$ cat dat/graph.txt
0 x x x x x
x 0 x x x x
x x 0 x x x
x x x 0 x x
x x x x 0 x
x x x x x 0
```

**output:**

```
$ /bin/rgraph dat/graph.txt

Properties of array read from file 'dat/graph.txt':

  elements: 36
  rows    : 6
  cols    : 6

Array elements:

     0 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999
 99999     0 99999 99999 99999 99999
 99999 99999     0 99999 99999 99999
 99999 99999 99999     0 99999 99999
 99999 99999 99999 99999     0 99999
 99999 99999 99999 99999 99999     0
```

Answer (score 0):

`#define x 99999` tells the compiler to treat the symbol `x` as the value 99999 *within the program*; it has no effect on how characters read from a file are treated.

Since you are explicitly telling `fscanf` that you expect to read an integer, there is no reason to expect it to anything reasonable (since you just lied to it).

What you *can* do is read in each symbol as a string, and if it is an `x`, do whatever is appropriate for your program to do; you can use utilities like `atoi` of `sscanf` to handle those that actually are integers.